# Changes not reflecting after pod deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

I am modifying the code in my project, and deploying it in kubernetes pod, the pod are deployed successfully, but the latest changes which I have made in my code are not being reflected after deployment, any idea for it?

Comment: Are you building a new container image with this new changes you have made?

Comment: I am again building my Dockerfile to create the image. After making my changes in code

Comment: when you change everything in a file that is part of the container image, you need to rebuild the image with `docker build`, if you don't this, kubernetes will take the same image without  the changes. In every change in the code a new build is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I did rebuild, but still changes are not reflecting

Comment: Besides this make sure the `imagePullPolicy` in your pod template is set to `IfNotPresent`, then kubelet will only try to pull the image if it is not present in the local machine

Comment: I have set to imagePullPolicy: "Always"

Comment: where did you change your code? Do you mean the yaml files which you use to deploy in kubernetes (the manifests) or did you change something inside your application which goes into your container?

Comment: Inside application only, my project code (In my case vue code)

Comment: Well, so I don't know haha, any extra info, like you yaml template, build procedure, etc.. will be welcome in order to help you. But for now is hard to know what could it be

Answer (score 2):

When you change the code inside your application which will be build into your container, you have to do the following:

1. Rebuild your image with the latest changes (e.g. via `docker build ...`)
2. Push the image to your registry (e.g. via `docker push ...`)
3. Update your manifests with the new container version (field `spec.containers.image`) or if it has the same version/tag, make sure you have the `imagePullPolicy` set to `Always`.
4. In case your manifests did not change (e.g. because the tag remains the same), you need to trigger a rollout in your deployment or delete your Pods manually to ensure it pull the image again and takes the latest changes.

If you're running a Webapp, you might need to clean your browser cache and reload all resources (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Comment: @SvDhote did this help you?